# Convert System.Action to String

Tags: c#

I have a function...

```
var neighbours =
    from x in Enumerable.Range(0, array2.GetLength(0))
        .Where(x => Math.Abs(x - refx) <= 1)
    from y in Enumerable.Range(0, array2.GetLength(1))
        .Where(y => Math.Abs(y - refy) <= 1)
    select new { x, y };
neighbours.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

this func working well.
But I want:

```
var neighbours =
    from x in Enumerable.Range(0, array2.GetLength(0))
        .Where(x => Math.Abs(x - refx) <= 1)
    from y in Enumerable.Range(0, array2.GetLength(1))
        .Where(y => Math.Abs(y - refy) <= 1)
    select new { x, y };
neighbours.ToList().ForEach(label3.Text);
```

It doesn't working.
So,I want convert System.Action To String...
Any idea for this?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, your last example makes no sense.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to display?

Comment: Are you trying to say you want label3.Text to a list of all results?

Comment: As you can see, your question has been downvoted. You should really make an effort to explain what you are trying to achieve. You would possibly get some upvotes...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't *really* want to convert an action to a string. You want to create an action which *does something* with a value. I *suspect* you may want something like:

```
neighbours.ToList().ForEach(x => label3.Text += x.ToString());
```

(It's hard to tell, but that's my best guess based on your sample code.)

That's pretty nasty though, in terms of string concatenation. Perhaps you want:

```
string text = string.Join("\r\n", neighbours);
label3.Text = text;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I think the equivalent of

```
neighbours.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

would be something like this:

```
neighbours.ToList().ForEach(AppendLabelLine);
```

where *AppendLabelLine* could be defined as:

```
private void AppendLabelLine(object o) {
   var sb = new StringBuilder(label3.Content as string);
   if (sb.Length > 0) sb.AppendLine();
   sb.Append(o);
   label3.Content = sb.ToString();
}
```

Or, the same using inline lambda expressions:

```
neighbours.ToList().ForEach(o => {
   var sb = new StringBuilder(label3.Content as string);
   if (sb.Length > 0) sb.AppendLine();
   sb.Append(o);
   label3.Content = sb.ToString();
});
```